# Pygame fails to load PNG image

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game as a coding exercise in my freetime and I have run into an issue. I placed 'rock.png' and 'tree.png' in the same file as my .py file... but I get this issue. I have made multiple games before this using the same method and I never had this issue.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys, math, random, os

w = 900
h = 900
size = (w,h)
surface = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('SkiFreeX')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
treeImage = pygame.image.load('tree.png')
rockImage = pygame.image.load('rock.png')
skierImage = pygame.image.load('images/skierStoppedRight.png')
```

I get the error:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open tree.png
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try `print(os.listdir("."))` to print the contents of the current directory to make sure that you're running your script where the file is available. You could also print `os.getcwd()` to return the current directory.

Comment: It's most likely a problem with the path or a typo in the image name, so double check if everything is spelled correctly. Is the 'tree.png' maybe in the 'images' directory as well?

Answer (score 1):

this is from the included chimp.py code if you download the full source of pygame.

then for each reference you need to call to file system use

```
main_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
data_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, "images")

treeImage = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(main_dir, 'tree.png'))
rockImage = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(main_dir,'rock.png'))
skierImage = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(data_dir, 'skierStoppedRight.png'))
```